# Binding a panels in Extjs

Tags: extjs4

Hello i have two panels west and center. Center is grid and west i want put some data from grid. How Can i get the west panet properties from the center panel?
I tryed this:
`var westPanel= Ext.getCmp('WestPanelId',{
 html: Hello world 
});`
This is the west panel:

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.portal.SettingsMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',    

    alias: 'widget.settings',

    initComponent: function() {

        Ext.apply(this, {

            title:'Settings',
            html: ExtMVC.util.Constants.shortBogusMarkup,
            border: false,
            autoScroll: true,
            iconCls: 'settings'

        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create a form in the west panel and listen to the `itemclick` event of the grid, then populate the form with the data you will receive in the `record` parameter of the `itemclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.portal.SettingsMenu', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias  : 'widget.settings',
    region : 'west',


    loadData: function(record){
        // Do what you want with the selected record
    }
});

Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.portal.Grid', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    region : 'center',

    initComponent : function(){
        this.on('itemclick', function(grid, record){
            grid.up()              // Go up the DOM tree to select the grid's parent component
                .down('settings')  // Go down the DOM Tree to select the component with the xtype "settings" (your west panel)
                .loadData(record); // Call the desired function on the component with the clicked record as parameter
        }, this);

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```